# Accessing another ribbon element in IRibbonExtensibility class

Tags: c#, vsto

I have a project in which I'm using the Office.IRibbonExtensibility inheritance.  The issue I'm having is that my project requires me to 'uncheck' a checkbox when a button is pressed on the ribbon.
As far as I can tell, only your currently selected control is accessible in code through the Office.IRibbonControl property of the button press handler.
So my question is, how do I access my checkbox element in the button click event in an XML based VSTO project?

Comment: Where does your checkbox element lies? Is it part of ribbon or a document element

Comment: Yes, it sits within the same 'tab' in the xml heirarchy.
<blink>
<ribbon> 
  <tabs>
     <group>
        <splitbutton>
           <button> <--  Click event on this guy
        </splitbutton>
        <checkbox> <-- check/uncheck this guy
</blink>

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

**Ribbon.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
              <group id="group1" label="group1">
                <button id ="btnTest" size="large" label="TestButton" onAction="btnTest_Click"/>
                <checkBox id ="chkTest" label="TestCheckbox" getPressed="chkTest_pressed" />
              </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

**Ribbon.cs**

```
private bool isChecked = false;
public void btnTest_Click(IRibbonControl ribbon)
{
    isChecked = true;
    this.ribbon.Invalidate();
}
public bool chkTest_pressed(IRibbonControl ribbon)
{
    return isChecked;
}
```

Comment: It's not a question of finding it's checked state.  it's trying to CHANGE it's checked state from the button click.

Comment: In the above code btnTest_Click will be called when the button is clicked and the ribbon.Invalidate will refresh your ribbon. chkTest_pressed will be called when your ribbon refreshes everytime.